# How to add a site to 'Local intranet' zone in internet options using a PowerShell script?

Tags: powershell

I would like to add \XX01234ABC01 to Local intranet zone using a PowerShell script and possibly take the site from the variable below.

$computername=$env:computername -replace ".....$","ABC01"

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you tried anything yet?

Comment: No still trying to figure a way to do it.

Comment: @RikeshPatel This should get you started: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/182569

Answer (score 1):

I hope this help you

```
$prefixIntranet = "www"
$LocalIntranetSite = "xxxx.com"

$UserRegPath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\ZoneMap\Domains"

$DWord = 1


try {     
  Write-Verbose "Creating a new key '$LocalIntranetSite' under $UserRegPath."
  New-Item -Path "$UserRegPath" -ItemType File -Name "$LocalIntranetSite"
  New-Item -Path "$UserRegPath\$LocalIntranetSite" -ItemType File -Name "$prefixIntranet"

  Write-Verbose "Creating a Dword value named 'HTTP' and set the value to '$DWord' "
  Set-ItemProperty -Path $UserRegPath\$LocalIntranetSite\$prefixIntranet -Name "http" -Value $DWord `
  Write-Host "Successfully added '$prefixIntranet.$LocalIntranetSite' domain to Internet Explorer local intranet." 
} Catch [System.Exception] {
  Write-Warning "[CATCH] Errors found during attempt:`n$_" -BackgroundColor Red
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was looking to do something similar. This will do the job:

```
# Gets you PC Name like you had in your question
$LocalIntranetSite = $env:computername -replace ".....$","ABC01"
# Set your base registry location
$UserRegPath = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet 
Settings\ZoneMap\Domains"
# Set your zone. 1 is intranet.
$DWord = 1

try {     
   Write-Debug "Creating a new key '$LocalIntranetSite' under $UserRegPath."
   # Check to be sure the key isn't already listed before trying to add
   if (-not (Test-Path -Path "$UserRegPath\$LocalIntranetSite")) {
     # Add your site to the domains list in the registry
     New-Item -Path "$UserRegPath" -ItemType File -Name "$LocalIntranetSite"
   }
  # Set a Dword property named '*' and with value '$DWord' on your '$LocalIntranetSite'. 
  # This is what adds your site to the Intranet Zone.
  Set-ItemProperty -Path "$UserRegPath\$LocalIntranetSite" -Name "*" -Value $DWord
} Catch [System.Exception] {
  Write-Warning "[CATCH] Errors found during attempt:`n$_"
}
```